# If one vector $u_k$ with coordinate $x_k$ approaches the other $v$ with coordinate $y$, does $x_k$ approaches $y$ regardless of the metric?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, metric-spaces

For any vector space $V$ over scalar field $F$, when a basis is chosen, a vector has a unique coordinate in $F^n$. We can define two metrics $d_1$, $d_2$ on $V$ and $F^n$ respectively, so that we can talk about limits. My question is, if one vector $u_k$ with coordinate $x_k$ approaches the other vector $v$ with coordinate $y$, with respect to $d_1$, does $x_k$ approaches $y$ regardless of the metric $d_2$? And what if we restrict $d_1$ and $d_2$ to be norm-induced?

This seems intuitively true and I can prove it for $\Bbb R^n$ and norm-induced metrics: use 2-norm (all norms are equivalent in $\Bbb R^n$, it does not matter which norm we choose), choose basis $B$, then $|u_k-v|^2 = (x_k-y)^TB^TB(x_k-y) \ge \alpha |x_k-y|$ for some constant $\alpha$ independent of $x_k$ since $B^TB$ is positive definite. The rest is easy.

But I am not sure if it holds in general. If not, any one can help show a counter example? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If $d_1$ and $d_2$ are norm-induced and $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space, then, yes ! All norms are equivalent in finite dimension, meaning we can always find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ strictly positive real numbers such that, for any two norms $\| \cdot \|_1 $ and $\| \cdot \|_2$,

\begin{equation*}
 \alpha \|\cdot\|_1 \leq \| \cdot \|_2 \leq \beta \|  \cdot\|_1 
\end{equation*}

Now, if $V$ is of infinite dimension, your claim is very wrong ; anything can happen. Take for instance $V = \mathbb{R}[X]$ the $\mathbb{R}$ vector space of polynomials having real coefficients. And let $Q$ be **any** polynomial of $\mathbb{R}[X]$. We are going to construct a norm $\| \cdot \| $ over $\mathbb{R}[X]$ such that $ X^n \underset{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow}  Q$  for the norm $\| \cdot \|$!
Let $d$ be the degree of $Q$ ; and let $P_k = X^k$ if $k \leq d$ and $P_k = 2^k (X^k -Q)$. The family of polynomials $\mathscr{B}=(P_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is clearly a basis of $\mathbb{R}[X]$. Let $\| \cdot \| $ be the $\sup$ norm related to the basis $\mathscr{B}$, that is :  if $R$ is any real polynomial, we write $R = \sum_{k=0}^r a_k P_k$ where $r$ is the degree of $R$ and $(a_k)_{0 \leq k \leq n}$ is a family of real numbers, and we set: 
\begin{equation*}
\| R\| = \underset{0 \leq k \leq n}{\sup}|a_k| 
\end{equation*}

Then for $k > d $ we have :

\begin{equation*}
\| X^k - Q \| = \frac{1}{2^k} \|2^k(X^k-Q)\| = \frac{1}{2^k} \underset{k \to \infty}{\longrightarrow}0
\end{equation*}

Thus the initial statement is proved

Now if $d_1$ and $d_2$ are not norm induced, your claim is pretty much always false in any case (except maybe pathological ones, where the only distance that exists is the trivial one). Take for instance $d_1$ the trivial distance, that is: $d_1(x,y)=0$ when $x=y$ and $d_1(x,y)=1$ if $x \neq y$.  You can check that a sequence of vectors $(x_k)$ converges, with respect to $d_1$, if and only if it is stationary for $k$ large enough. Take then any distance $d_2$ which differs form the trivial distance and you are done !